# Where to ask this question?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I am looking for one of the Stack Exchange websites to ask this question: `Is there a 'cloud' (online file storage) in which I can store applications from my computer?`

Note that I am currently using a Mac. I am unaware whether or not Dropbox will do this, or even Box.

Answer (score 3):

[Superuser](https://superuser.com/) surely? There are currently 55 questions tagged [cloud](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cloud)...

Comment: It might run afoul of the "no shopping recommendations" rule on SU, but it's probably worth a shot. Web Apps would be my second choice, but it's a stretch.

Comment: @Anna agreed...I guess the "stores applications" and Mac part of it lends itself to SuperUser...if it were purely a Dropbox or Box question then webapps would be closer...